# What should I do if I am doubting whether I am pure or not?

Tags: fiqh, taharah, nocturnal-emission

Recently, I have been having a lot of doubts about whether I am pure or not. The other day, I went to sleep for about an hour and after a few minutes of waking up, I went to the toilet and found a very small mark on my pants. I Did not know if this was urine or water or madhi. I don't remember having a wet dream or sperm release so I just washed it off.

But now, I keep having doubts about  whether I am pure or not. I am worried because I prayed and fasted in that state. Will my fast and prayers be accepted?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. I strongly suggest you to visit our [help] and take the [tour] to learn more about the site and model.

Comment: I suggest that you perform ghusl and Seek Allah's forgiveness.

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't semen, you're pure. But if you stay skeptical about being impure, I suggest that you **perform ghusl** to take all doubts and suspicions away.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE unlike the typical internet, we expect answers here to be **well elaborated**, focused on answering the initial question and **claims supported by evidences**. therefore I strongly suggest you to read [answer], visit our [help] and take the [tour] to learn more about the site and model.

Answer (score 0):

Wlaykumusaslam
Sometimes its happen and i have found that wet dreams happened sometimes and you are unknown about it so better way is you should gushl before you pray or anything related with it.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. I strongly suggest you to visit our [help](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help) center and take the [tour](http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site and mode